# Unique set of words from string C++

Tags: c++, unique

I am trying to write a function that inputs an array_string and finds unique words, then copies them over to unique_array. This is a bit over my head I feel like and need some advice on where to go from here..

```
void unique140(string str_array[], int array_size, string unique_array[], int&unique_size)
{
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;

for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
  for(j = 0; j < unique_size; j++)
  if (str_array[i] != unique_array[j])
  {unique_array[i];}
  if(str_array[i] == unique_array[j]
  break;
 }
```

Comment: [`unique`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/) function.

Comment: I forgot to say that I cannot use that function. I have to make one myself.

Comment: @gongzhitaao, Rather, `std::unique_copy`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
void unique140(string str_array[], int array_size, 
                 string unique_array[], int&unique_size)
{
    unordered_map<string,int> count;
    for(int i=0; i<array_size; i++) {
        count[str_array[i]]++;
    }
    unique_size = 0;
    for(auto it=count.begin(); it!=count.end(); ++it) {
        if(it->second==1) {
            unique_array[unique_size++] = it->first;
        }
    }
}
```

use a std::map if you dont have a std::unordered_map.

Answer (score 0):

You're not a million miles away, the loops look good. Now you have to use those loops to make a decision, is the word `str_array[i]` present in the `unique_array` or not? Now just a minutes thought will tell you that `str_array[i]` is present if *any one* of the equality tests `str_array[i] == unique_array[j]` is true. Here's how to code that

```
for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
    bool in_unique_array = false;
    for(j = 0; j < unique_size; j++)
       if (str_array[i] == unique_array[j])
           in_unique_array = true;
    ...
}
```

Next we have to add `str_array[i]` to `unique_array` if it's not already there. So that's

```
for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
    bool in_unique_array = false;
    for(j = 0; j < unique_size; j++)
       if (str_array[i] == unique_array[j])
           in_unique_array = true;
    if (!in_unique_array)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally having decided to add the string to `unique_array` we have to do that

```
for(i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
{
    bool in_unique_array = false;
    for(j = 0; j < unique_size; j++)
       if (str_array[i] == unique_array[j])
           in_unique_array = true;
    if (!in_unique_array)
    {
        unique_array[unique_size] = str_array[i];
        unique_size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: when `present`, you could `break` :)

Comment: @gongzhitaao Yes, I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP

Comment: So this is saying.. if the element is not in unique array, copy it to unique_array[j]?       if (!in_unique_array) { unique_array[j]}    Still confused :(

Comment: This is still bad code. its O(N^2), when it could easily be N(logN) or even O(N)

Comment: @RichardPlunkett Given that the OP is struggling to understand this code do you think a more efficient version would be more useful to him?

Comment: @user3042929 Are you saying you're not sure how to copy from str_array to unique_array? That's very easy just use `=` to copy the string and then adjust the size. Or are you saying that I've misunderstood what you are trying to do? In any case I've editted the above post.

Comment: @john a fair enough thought. The map based answer seems to me to be simpler code, though introducing another type may dwarf that for OP.